# Unable to create JDBC datasource instance - Spring 4.x and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I am using Spring 4.x libraries, Java 8 and Tomcat 8

Below is my datasource configuration.

**my_app/META_INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/my_app" swallowOutput="true">
<Resource name="jdbc/paymentDB" auth="Container" type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
 driverClassName="${driverClassName}"
 url="${url}" 
 username="${username}"
 password="${password}"
 initialSize="10"
 maxIdle="30"
 validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
 maxActive="30"
 maxWait="5000"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 validationQueryTimeout="1"
 jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=2);org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1000,maxQueries=200)"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"/>
</Context>
```

**My web.xml entry**

```
<resource-ref>
      <res-ref-name>
        jdbc/paymentDB
      </res-ref-name>
      <res-type>
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
      </res-type>
      <res-auth>
        Container
      </res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

**Entry in my applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
         <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/paymentDB"></property>
    </bean>
```

I have added necessary driver jars in tomcat lib/ folder. When I am starting my application I am getting below exception.

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone has any idea as what am I missing here.

**UPDATE: I have created the context.xml file inside src/main/webapp folder in my eclipse maven project**

**UPDATE**

I am using variables in my context.xml i.e ${driverClassName} which spring loads form envrionment specific property files, My question is will this work because as soon as the application gets loaded into container it will try to load web.xml which has reference to my spring applicationContext.xml as well as this datasource which I have defined in the context.xml

**Update after replacing variables with actual values**

Looks like it is doing somehing but not I am getting different flavor of exception

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory]
```

**Final Update**

I changed my factory value from `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`

and It worked.

Comment: Did you try using plain variable instead of env variables?

Comment: Thanks Rossi for the help

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

In you context.xml,

```
<Resource name="jdbc/paymentDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
 driverClassName="${driverClassName}"
 url="${url}" 
 username="${username}"
 password="${password}"
 initialSize="10"
 maxIdle="30"
 validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
 maxActive="30"
 maxWait="5000"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 validationQueryTimeout="1"
 jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=2);org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1000,maxQueries=200)"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"/>
```

Comment: I do not want to change anything in Tomcat's server.xml and context.xml hence I have defined my own context.xml

Comment: Then: do you have this jar (tomcat-jdbc.jar) in your path?

Comment: Yes I have this jar in tomcat /lib as well as in my application pom

Comment: You missed the factory parameter which is factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" and the type should be type="javax.sql.DataSource". Let me know if it works

Comment: Added this missing paramters but still no breakthrough :(

Comment: Are there any other log messages?